# Looper routing ideas?

Tags: amplifiers, looping

I need a little help with routing lines and looper

I need to get this setup:

1. the input (it's a hurdygurdy put doesn't matter) goes via a on/off pedal to the looper and then to the loop monitor (a 5w vox portable amp)
2. the looper output and the hg input goes to a single output channel

I need to send the hg line to the looper during the loop recording then to "cut" the line to avoid that the hg melody goes to the monitor too, because the hg is very loud and the melody will be louder than the loop

Sometime I play with other people, so I need to have a single output to go to the main amp system, thus the need to mix the hg line before the looper and the looper output BEFORE the monitor amp.

The missing part, for me, is just *how* to mix the two signals.

I already have a jamman looper pedal and I got some skills with electronics and wood, so I'll build the needed parts by myself.

Comment: actually that will be a solution, since i may send the sampler-only output to the monitor and still have the mixed output free, all i have to make is a splitter stereo/L+R, right?
point is, i have a jamman express xt that's actually mono/stereo (left/mono + right singled in and out) so first i have to look into the electronics...and YES, the jacks seems all stereo (at least the jacks are, i'll have to check the wiring)

Comment: A small mixer and a foot controlled volume pedal would probably do the job - using the stereo to produce two discrete channels as needed.